# Error using Nominatim API : HTTPSConnectionPool ... Max retries exceeded ... Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, connection-pooling, geopy, nominatim

I'm new to the Geopy library and the Nominatim library and I've encountred a problem.

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of an adress using the Nominatim API inside a Jupyter Notebook with a proxy (that I can't desactivate) on my computer. Here is my code :

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.distance import geodesic as GD
import requests
import urllib3

def adress_latitude_longitude(adress):
    proxy = "http://localhost:8888"
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ScriptAdress",proxies={"http":proxy})
    location = geolocator.geocode(adress)

    if location is not None:
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        return latitude,longitude
    else:
        print("adress not found:" + adress)
        return 

adress_latitude_longitude("6 Jean Jaures 35000 Rennes")
```

But I get this error message :
GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=6+Jean+Jaures+35000+Rennes&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F4A1BC5650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

I tried to look online on how to get rid of this problem.
I've seen people talking about not having correctly enabled their proxy, not having a stable connexion among other things but nothing that helped with my problem.

Thank you in advance.